# ionic 4 protractor e2e - how to select/distinguish between ionic alerts buttons

Tags: protractor, ionic4, end-to-end

I want to be able to simply and reliable select these two alert buttons for e2e testing with protractor.

I can't use by.partialButtonText since the text is inside a span element.

```html
<button type="button" class="alert-button ion-focusable ion-activatable sc-ion-alert-md" tabindex="0">
     <span class="alert-button-inner sc-ion-alert-md">Yes</span>
     <ion-ripple-effect class="sc-ion-alert-md md hydrated" role="presentation"></ion-ripple-effect>
</button>
<button type="button" class="alert-button ion-focusable ion-activatable sc-ion-alert-md" tabindex="0">
     <span class="alert-button-inner sc-ion-alert-md">No</span>
     <ion-ripple-effect class="sc-ion-alert-md md hydrated" role="presentation"></ion-ripple-effect>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are they always displayed in that particular order in the DOM?
If that is the case, you could try the following:

```
const yesButton = element.all(by.css('.alert-button-inner.sc-ion-alert-md')).get(0);

const noButton = element.all(by.css('.alert-button-inner.sc-ion-alert-md')).get(1);
```

Those will get the `<span>` element.

Additionally, you could try to locate them more precisely with the following method:

```
const yesButton = element(by.cssContainingText('.alert-button-inner.sc-ion-alert-md', 'Yes'));  

const noButton = element(by.cssContainingText('.alert-button-inner.sc-ion-alert-md', 'No'));
```